# DB2, optimize an update query

Tags: sql, db2

I have this query:

```
update product a 
  set a.tsinsert = (select b.tsinsert 
                      from h_product b 
                     where b.tsinsert is not null and 
                           a.product_id = b.product_id);
```

This query doesn't end.
Can I write it otherwise?

Comment: What is not clear? I have a query not optimized that doesn't end it takes more than 1 hour without a result. How can I optimize it or write it otherwise ?

Comment: is product_id the key? you may try changing the order of conditions in your where clause like `where a.product_id = b.product_id and b.tsinsert is not null`

Comment: This question and the answer are completely unclear when we don't know anything about the data or task.  Is it taking too long because the tables are really big?  Do you have a join error?  Do you need to update every row?  Who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this query and it works:

```
merge into  product a using (select distinct product_id ,TSINSERT  from  h_product where tsinsert is not null order by product_id ) b
                on (a.product_id = b.product_id ) 
                when matched then update set a.tsinsert = b.TSINSERT;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
update product a 
  set a.tsinsert = (select b.tsinsert 
                      from h_product b 
                     where b.tsinsert is not null and 
                           a.product_id = b.product_id);
```

You want an index on `h_product(product_id, tsinsert)`.  I am surprised that the query doesn't have a `where` clause, because this will set `a.tsinsert` to `NULL` when there are no matches.